# How can I re-organize php array of sports

Tags: php, sql-server, foreach

I'm trying to list sport league offerings for intramurals. My current php foreach spits out all the leagues and offerings. Great.

[image: all IM offerings]

Now I want to only show 1 instance of the sport (course), like "Basketball" and then list the multiple league offerings (offering) in columns.

I can't do another loop based on 
if $nt['course'] == "Basketball" because these will change

[image]

Not sure if my mssql query needs to change or if I can use another foreach loop?

query

```
$sql2 = SELECT category
,course 
,offering
,Semester
,spots
,registerLink from dbtable WHERE semester like "%Fall 2016%" and category like "%Leagues%" ORDER BY course

$rs= mssql_query ($sql2, $con)
or die("Error!");

$result = array();
if (mssql_num_rows($rs)) {
    while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
        $result[] = $row;
    }
}
return $result;
exit();
```

my foreach loop in view:

```
<?php 
foreach ($data as $nt) {
echo "<div class='col-md-2'>";
echo "<h2><a href='#'>".$nt['course']."</a></h2>";
echo "<h3>".$nt['offering']."</h3>";
echo "<h4>".$nt['Semester']."</h4>";
echo "<p>".$nt['spots']."</p>";
echo "<button>".$nt['registerLink']."</button>";
echo "</div>";
}
```

So just to clarify:
category = "Leagues" which is in my query
course = Basketball and Flag Football, etc

Comment: instead  of `$result[] = $row;` do  `$result[ $row['course']][] = $row;` ad then print_r($result); to check result comes in desired format or not?

Comment: put that in as an answer and I'll choose it. THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple:-

instead of

`$result[] = $row;`

do

`$result[ $row['course']][] = $row;`

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
$result = array();
if (mssql_num_rows($rs)) {
    while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
        if(!in_array($row["course"], $result))
        {
          array_push($result, $row["course"]);
        }
        array_push($result[$row["course"]], $row);
    }
}
return $result;
```

And loop in view:

```
foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
  echo "<h1>".$key."</h1>";
  foreach($value as $nt)
  {
    echo "<div class='col-md-2'>";
    echo "<h3>".$nt['offering']."</h3>";
    echo "<h4>".$nt['Semester']."</h4>";
    echo "<p>".$nt['spots']."</p>";
    echo "<button>".$nt['registerLink']."</button>";
    echo "</div>";
  }
}
```

Comment: May be i am wrong, but i don't think this much stuff needed (if you look output closely)

Comment: that gets me: array(8) { [0]=> string(10) "Basketball" ["Basketball"]=> NULL [1]=> string(13) "Flag Football" ["Flag Football"]=> NULL [2]=> string(6) "Futsal" ["Futsal"]=> NULL [3]=> string(6) "Soccer" ["Soccer"]=> NULL }

Comment: @sloga  did you checked my comment. do once and then print that result and check your desired output coming or not?

Comment: @Anant yes! your comment worked. Please submit as answer, thank you!!